# Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error asking dialect to register ref cursor parameter [5]

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, stored-procedures

When I execute the code below, I get the following error on line spq.execute(). Could you give me some tip about whats wrong, please?

```
StoredProcedureQuery spq = emOracle.createStoredProcedureQuery("SDBANCO.PRC_CNS_SLD_JUD_BLOQ_DESBLOQ");
    spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

    // set input parameter
    spq.setParameter(1, BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(agencia)));
    spq.setParameter(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(conta)));
    spq.setParameter(3, BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(codigoBloqueioLegado)));
    spq.setParameter(4, cpfCnpj);

    BloqueioJudicial bloqueioJudicial = null;
    try{
        if (spq.execute()) {
            bloqueioJudicial = (BloqueioJudicial) spq.getSingleResult();
            return bloqueioJudicial.getSaldoBloqueado();
        }
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        return new BigDecimal(0);
    }

    return new BigDecimal(0);
```

Error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error asking dialect to register ref cursor parameter [5]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.cursor.internal.StandardRefCursorSupport.registerRefCursorParameter(StandardRefCursorSupport.java:60)
>       at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.prepare(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:347)
>       at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:402)
>       at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:363)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217)
>       at br.com.company.juridico.repository.impl.CartNetRepositoryImpl.consultarSaldoBloqueadoContaProduto(CartNetRepositoryImpl.java:155)
>       at br.com.company.juridico.repository.impl.CartNetRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$60a23375.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>       ... 98 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: -99
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:4188)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:129)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:326)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:574)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1585)
>       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CachedCallableStatement.java:153)
>       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(WrappedCallableStatement.java:1168)
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect.registerResultSetOutParameter(Oracle8iDialect.java:552)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.cursor.internal.StandardRefCursorSupport.registerRefCursorParameter(StandardRefCursorSupport.java:57)
>       ... 109 more

Comment: Tip: check this line of error: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: -99 at `

Comment: I'm not finding which column and what's wrong with it.

Comment: show us the definition of the stored procedure.. using jpa annotations

Comment: Did you try to run the stored procedure in database?

Comment: Added stored procedure above. Check it please.

Comment: i executed the stored procedure, and it's sql works.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski what did you mean. Am I forgetting to do something?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Oracle Libraries are in the application classpath, and use OracleTypes.class like this:

spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, **OracleTypes.class**, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try declare ref_cursor first.

```cs
StoredProcedureQuery spq = emOracle.createStoredProcedureQuery("SDBANCO.PRC_CNS_SLD_JUD_BLOQ_DESBLOQ");
spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
```

and

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SDBANCO.PRC_CNS_SLD_JUD_BLOQ_DESBLOQ( 
            PRESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, 
            PNR_AGENCIA IN NUMBER, 
            PNR_CONTA IN NUMBER, 
            PNR_CODBLOQUEIOJUD IN NUMBER, 
            PVCH_CPFCNPJ IN VARCHAR2)
AS
```